# Bootstrap 3 - Bottom align column within row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two Bootstrap columns within a row, thusly:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 mainBox">
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <h2>Sub Heading</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 mainBox buttonBox">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the second column to be bottom aligned vertically within the row.  How do I achieve this?

Here is a demo fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/RationalGeek/6pYhx/

Comment: Why do you create two columns?  Why not have two rows with a col-md-12 in both?  Not understanding what you want the final product to look like.

Comment: I want the two sections to be side-to-side, not one on top of another.  But I want them to be bottom aligned.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using `position: absolute;` and setting a `bottom` of `0`:

```
.row {
    position: relative;
}
.mainBox {
    border: solid thin black;
}    
.buttonBox {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6pYhx/3/

Comment: You need to add `padding-bottom` to `.mainBox` element, to prevent content overlapping also.

Comment: This will take the column out of the flow, so be careful if you include additional columns in this row.

Comment: I think @Dismissile might have hit my issue on the head - this seems to work in the Fiddle but not in my actual code.  I will play around and either get it to work or clarify the demo.

Comment: Yeah the position: absolute was the key, although needing position: relative on the parent is what was tripping me up.

Answer (score 10):

Although absolute position is a quick fix, a more robust solution that works with many columns would be much better.

Here is my solution in this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pYhx/207/).

```
[class*='cols-'].row > *{
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block; 
  /* old ie fixes */
  *zoom: 1; 
  *display: inline;
}

.row.cols-bottom > *{
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.row.cols-middle > *{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and html:

```
<div class="row cols-bottom">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <h4>Sub Heading</h4>
    <!-- The lack of space between div tags below does MATTER -->
    </div><div class="col-xs-4">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Button </button>
    <!-- The lack of space between div tags below does MATTER -->
    </div><div class='col-xs-4'>
        This col should be 3
    </div>
</div>
```

There are a couple of things to note in my solution. The inline-block strategy used allows positioning of the div columns to stay in the flow of the document, while also allowing the use of vertical-align styling. I've included a style for bottom alignment and middle alignment for you convenience (I tend to use the middle alignment just as often).

The second thing to note is you **must** have each of the respective ending-column `</div>` and starting-column `<div>` meet with **no** space in between. This is because inline-block gives 'space' to any character (including a space character). Essentially, it is because a space character has a given font-size, which ends up pushing the respective right most columns underneath the left most columns. There are hacks to overcome this, but they are **note** cross-browser compatible, so I did not include them. Therefore, my solution is hack-free, and works with multiple columns. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

Building on Mike's solution, here's one that does not care about spaces between divs. Instead of inline it uses display:table and display:cell.

```
[class*='cols-'] {
   display:table;
}
[class*='cols-'] > * {
    float: none;
    position: relative;
    /* old ie fixes */
    *zoom: 1; 
    *display: inline;
    display: table-cell;
}
.cols-bottom > * {
        vertical-align: bottom;
}
.cols-top > * {
        vertical-align: top;
}

//extra bonus if needed
.p-top {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

plunker updated: http://jsfiddle.net/6pYhx/325/

Comment: If you want to maintain col-12 behavior while also using this method, you'll need to use media queries to override behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm posting on a *very* old thread, but I've been searching for solutions to the same issue.  I *think* a simple solution may be to use `display: flex;` on the row, and `margin-top: auto;` on the column you want pushed down.  Here's a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ftssvdyo/1/) based on the OP.

*Please note* - this is altering the `row` class which could have unintended side effects.  You may want to implement it in a new class and only apply where needed.

Answer (score 1):

Building on solutions from Mike and JPH, this allows for col-12 behavior to be retained. It isn't perfect and a bit verbose in plain CSS, but works.

```
/* Vertical Align Columns */
[class*='cols-'] {
   display:table;
}
.cols-bottom > * {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.cols-middle > * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.cols-top > * {
    vertical-align: top;
}

/* Resets for col-12 classes */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    [class*='cols-'] > *:not(.col-lg-12) {
        float: none;
        position: relative;
        /* old ie fixes */
        *zoom: 1; 
        *display: inline;
        display: table-cell;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    [class*='cols-'] > *:not(.col-lg-12):not(.col-md-12) {
        float: none;
        position: relative;
        /* old ie fixes */
        *zoom: 1; 
        *display: inline;
        display: table-cell;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    [class*='cols-'] > *:not(.col-lg-12):not(.col-md-12):not(.col-sm-12) {
        float: none;
        position: relative;
        /* old ie fixes */
        *zoom: 1; 
        *display: inline;
        display: table-cell;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    [class*='cols-'] > *:not(.col-lg-12):not(.col-md-12):not(.col-sm-12):not(.col-xs-12) {
        float: none;
        position: relative;
        /* old ie fixes */
        *zoom: 1; 
        *display: inline;
        display: table-cell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another working example
http://jsfiddle.net/RationalGeek/6pYhx/

```
<div class="row row-eq-height"></div>
```

The Css:

```
.row-eq-height {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display:         flex;
}
.mainBox {
   border: solid thin black;
}

.buttonBox {
    vertical-align:center;
    margin-top: auto;
   margin-bottom: auto;
}
```