# How to align vertically an element to the bottom within a bootstrap column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I'm using twitter-bootstrap framework, and [bootstrap touchspin plugin](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-touchspin/). And I want to align the touchspin at the bottom of an column `.col-md-6` which has **variable height**.

I tried adding the following (like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21630490/2154101)):

```
.row {
    position: relative;
}

.bootstrap-touchspin {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

But nothing changes. ([see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R5n9j/2/embedded/result/))

Why does it not work? Do you have another way to do it?

Here is a jsfiddle where you can try: **http://jsfiddle.net/R5n9j/1/**

---

**ACTUAL OUTPUT**

[image]

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

[image]

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div id="form-guardar-medidas">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" id="add-medida-medir">Tab1</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#tab2">Tab2</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div id='content' class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active fade in" id="tab1">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam blandit mattis pretium. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
                                <input id="input-cm" type="text" class="input-lg" name="input-cm">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">Hello tab2</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    padding: 20px;
}

.tab-content {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name='input-cm']").TouchSpin();

    $('.nav-tabs a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By switching to CSS table layout, you can have columns of same height for free, with the constraint of not being able to relatively position "(visual) cells" (in Firefox, at least) so you must do that on the '(visual) table"

EDIT2: `.bootstrap-touchspin` is also displayed as table and that fails in Chrome. Adding a div around this component that'll be absolutely positioned (and not the component itself anymore) solves this problem.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R5n9j/9/
Compatibility is IE8+ (because of / thanks to `display: table` and `table-cell`)

HTML

```
<div class="table pos-reference">
    <div class="cell">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
    </div>
    <div class="cell has-touchspin">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam blandit mattis pretium. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
        <div class="pos-abs">
            <input id="input-cm" type="text" class="input-lg" name="input-cm">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.pos-reference {
    position: relative;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.has-touchspin {
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 50px; /* Avoids superposition of content and absolutely positioned touchspin */
}
.pos-abs {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 1px solid #F00;
}
```

---

EDIT: Explanation about why your attempt at positioning the `.input-group` failed: TWBS `.col-AZ-NN` are already relatively positioned so the closest ancestor to `.input-group` being positioned isn't the one you set but `.col-md-6`. See Firebug screenshot below. Otherwise, your attempt was a good one ;)

[image: Twitter Bootstrap is positioning relatively all its columns, as shown in Firebug]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but (at least) in chrome the padding-bottom of tab-content is not respected (bigger than the other sides), and the touchspin control protrudes out of the tab-content to the right.

Comment: +1. This works on safari too and is definitely a better approach.

Comment: Ah, exact sorry. Hadn't test in Chrome yet. The touchspin is also using `display: table` and the width calculation seems very different between Firefox and Chrome in this case. By encapsulating the touchspin in an element that'll be absolutely positioned (and not the component itself), that solves the issue. Seems also OK in IE8

Comment: Hey, If I remove `margin-bottom: 20px;` returns the result that I'm looking for. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use flex:

```
.tab-pane .row{
    display:flex;
}
```

If you notice the height of the two `col-md-6` containers inside the tabs, they are not equal, flex when used applies equal height to its child containers.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jHM8T/embedded/result/)**

#### Limitation:

The Safari browser does *not* support the `flex` property.

Comment: Thanks, but what a pity. I'm afraid I need a good browser support.

Comment: @JohnDoe On looking around a bit, it seems like `display: -webkit-box;` could serve as a flex alternative. You can test this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/3EHYU/) in your safari browser, but again, conclusively, flex is not [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/flexbox).

Comment: Hey, you give me an idea, look this: http://jsfiddle.net/R5n9j/12/embedded/result/

Comment: @JohnDoe Ah, I see you have used a javascript approach. Works well too.

Comment: To be more explicit, neither IE8 nor IE9 support flex. That's 6% of maketshare in my country, according to StatCounter (though IE8 may drop now that XP is officially not supported by MS anymore)

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

I've added `col1` and `col2` ids to each columns, and with js I set the same height.

```
col1h = $("#col1").height();
col2h = $("#col2").height();

if (col1h > col2h) {
    def_height = col1h;
} else {
    def_height = col2h;
}

$("#col1,#col2").height(def_height);
```

And adding `left: 15px;` to `.bootstrap-touchspin`.

**The result http://jsfiddle.net/R5n9j/16/embedded/result**

Comment: What about the case where the 2nd column is taller than the 1st one? Why... the 10px is needed? (it should be 15) There's a 15px left padding on parent `.col-md-6` as shown by DevTools/Firebug (that's half of the gutter)

Comment: Thanks! :) Check it out the new solution.